# How to handle Firebase login as first access

Tags: firebase, navigation, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm writing a Flutter application which integrates Firebase Authentication.

### The problem

I would like to integrate in the best and most optimal way possible the authentication checking if the user is authenticated in the moment the app is launched. If the user is authenticated the app opens the normal home page, otherwise the authentication page is shown. After the authentication the app should redirect the user to the normal home page. For obvious reasons the user mustn't have the possibility to tap the back button and go back to the authentication page.

### What I've done so far

At the moment the application checks in the `main()` if the user is authenticated, and, if it is so, it creates a `MaterialApp` with, as `home`, the main page of the application. In that case, the `'/'` of the app is the home page. If it is not, the app creates a `MaterialApp` with, as `home`, the authentication screen. In that case, however, the `'/'` is the welcome screen, and so I can't use

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'))
```

(which, in fact, happens to be quite necessary and useful), because the `'/'` is not the home page, and, moreover, the user could tap the back button and get back to the welcome screen.

### The question

What am I losing? Am I completely wrong, and there is a totally different way of doing what I want to do, or the base is correct? If so, how can I implement what I would like to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Navigator.pushReplacement` or `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html

Here's a quick sample code.

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("First screen"),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to second screen"),
          onPressed: () => _goToSecondScreen(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _goToSecondScreen(context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Second screen"),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to first screen"),
          onPressed: () => _goToFirstScreen(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _goToFirstScreen(context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstScreen()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I can set as `settings` of the `MaterialPageRoute` `name: '/'` and it will ovverride the original `'/'`?
The `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'))` will bring me always to the right place?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `pushReplacement` will change the current route to the one you give it. So if you start from a login screen and push replacement to a home screen, now pressing back will exit the app.

Comment: I'd need to use `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'))`, and I need that `'/'` represents my home page, not the authentication page, and If I launch the application with the authentication page as home, `'/'` will represent the authentication page. If after I use `new MaterialPageRoute((builder) => new HomePage(), settings: new RouteSettings(name: '/')` the `'/'` will be replaced by the new one?

Comment: `'/'` is a named route you need to have configured (see [docs](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/named-routes/)). If you're currently in a screen previously configured as `'/'` and you call `pushReplacement` you don't reassign a route to `'/'`, you're just navigating to a different screen.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do, but if you want to pop all routes in your app and push a new one you can do so with something like `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstScreen()), (_) => false)`.

Comment: Actually I tried, and I solved my problem using `pushReplacement` and `MaterialPageRoute((builder) => new HomePage(), settings: new RouteSettings(name: '/')` and actually it takes that route as root route of the app, because `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'))` takes me right there.
Thank you